# Inserting information in database with PHP

Tags: php, css, sql, database, html

I'm a beginner and I am trying to learn PHP and SQL. I've written the code below so I can insert data into my database but I do not understand why it is not working. It loads and everything but when I click on the "Sign Up" button, it does nothing. Can someone help me figure it out?

```
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];


            $query = "INSERT INTO users1(username,password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("problem inserting new product into database");
        }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign Up</title>

<style>


button {
    text-align:center;
    color: gray;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<h3>Enter your data to register</h3>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">

    <label class="user-name">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" autofocus required"><br><br>
    <label class="pass-word"> Password: </label><input type="password" name="pass" class="info" placeholder="Enter your Password" required ><br><br>

    <button class="lbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">Sign Up</button>
    <p>Already registered? <a href="login2.php">Login</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your button needs `name="submit"`

Comment: If you're just starting out, **now** would be a good time to look up [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) before bad habits set in ;)

Comment: I'll definitely look it up

Comment: On a side note, your labels need a `for` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all**

If form redirects you to the same page you can leave `action` parameter empty: `action=""`

**Secondly**

You check if variable `$_POST['submit']` exists but none of your elements in form has name `submit` so it will never exist. Html form sends variables to array `$_POST` using names of fields as keys. If name is not given it is a number.

**What to do**

Add `name="submit"` to your submit `button` and that should work.

Change `name="pass"` to `name="password"` in your password `input` or change in php `$_POST['password']` to `$_POST['pass']`.

Also close your form (`</form>`). Modern browsers close it automaticly but it is still incorrect.

**Additional hints**

Accessing `$_POST` directly is not a good practice. Here is a better solution: `$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username')` instead of `$username = $_POST['username']`

It is also a good idea to use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function when inserting variables to SQL query.
Example: `$username = filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, $username)`

Answer (score 2):

Try to close the form.

```
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" 
  method="POST">

 <label class="user-name">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" 
 placeholder="Enter your username" autofocus required"><br><br>
<label class="pass-word"> Password: </label><input type="password" 
name="pass" class="info" placeholder="Enter your Password" required ><br> 
<br>

 <button class="lbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">Sign Up</button>
 <p>Keni nje adrese? <a href="login2.php">Futu</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: It can't. There is no field with `name='submit'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are  doing this way, the submit button should have a name, which will include it in the post array.

```
<button class="lbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Sign Up</button>
```

On th form submit, post array is created for all the elements inside the form having a valid name attribute.

You also need to close `<form></form>`